# Error in Magento Check out page

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, zend-framework

a:5:{i:0;s:362:"parse_ini_file() [function.parse-ini-file]: Unable to access /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/../../config/citruspay.ini
parse_ini_file(/home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/../../config/citruspay.ini) [function.parse-ini-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory";i:1;s:1290:"#0 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/Zend/Config/Ini.php(202): Zend_Config_Ini->_parseIniFile('/home/iyurway2/...')

## 1 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/Zend/Config/Ini.php(126): Zend_Config_Ini->_loadIniFile('/home/iyurway2/...')

## 2 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/CitrusPay_Moto_Block_Form_Pay.php(56): Zend_Config_Ini->__construct('/home/iyurway2/...', 'production')

## 3 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(2592): CitrusPay_Moto_Block_Form_Pay->_toHtml()

## 4 /home/iyurway2/public_html/app/code/community/CitrusPay/Moto/controllers/IndexController.php(9): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()

## 5 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13969): CitrusPay_Moto_IndexController->indexAction()

## 6 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18339): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')

## 7 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(17873): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

## 8 /home/iyurway2/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20473): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

## 9 /home/iyurway2/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

## 10 /home/iyurway2/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')

## 11 {main}";s:3:"url";s:18:"/moto/index/index/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}

Here is the error log file and when I try to check out in the site ( its supposed to redirect to payement gateway ) its printing this.

Comment: This is hardly readable

Answer (score 0):

`config/citruspay.ini` file is missing

Comment: Can you please help me locate that file ? .

Comment: Run command `find / -name citruspay.ini`. Does it find any files?

Comment: I fount it @public_html/app/code/community/CitrusPay/Moto/config